# how to get a class property?

Tags: apex, json

I have 2 class:

```
public class FromJSON {

    public cls_coord coord;
    public cls_weather[] weather;
    public String base; //stations
    public cls_main main;
    public Integer visibility;  //10000
    public cls_wind wind;
    public cls_clouds clouds;
    public Integer dt;  //1485789600
    public cls_sys sys;
    public Integer id;  //2643743
    public String name; //London
    public Integer cod; //200

    class cls_coord {
        public Double lon;  //-0.13
        public Double lat;  //51.51
    }
    class cls_weather {
        public Integer id;  //300
        public String main; //Drizzle
        public String description;  //light intensity drizzle
        public String icon; //09d
    }
    class cls_main {
        public Double temp; //280.32
        public Integer pressure;    //1012
        public Integer humidity;    //81
        public Double temp_min; //279.15
        public Double temp_max; //281.15
    }
    class cls_wind {
        public Double speed;    //4.1
        public Integer deg; //80
    }
    class cls_clouds {
        public Integer all; //90
    }
    class cls_sys {
        public Integer type;    //1
        public Integer id;  //5091
        public Double message;  //0.0103
        public String country;  //GB
        public Integer sunrise; //1485762037
        public Integer sunset;  //1485794875
    }
}

public with sharing class UpdateWeather {

    public FromJSON updateWeather() {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setEndpoint('https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        FromJSON weather = new FromJSON();
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            weather = (FromJSON) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), FromJSON.class);
             System.debug('weather = ' + weather);

             System.debug('weather = ' + weather.main.temp_min); //Type is not visible: FromJSON.cls_main
        }       
        return weather;
    }
}
```

here I get an error:

```
System.debug('weather = ' + weather.main.temp_min);
```

> Type is not visible: FromJSON.cls_main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default [access modifier](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm) in Apex is `private`.

For your inner classes to be visible to code outside their parent class, you need to explicitly declare them `public`, e.g.,

```
public class cls_main {
    public Double temp; //280.32
    public Integer pressure;    //1012
    public Integer humidity;    //81
    public Double temp_min; //279.15
    public Double temp_max; //281.15
}
```

Comment: How to get Object FromJSON in lwc?, console.log('weather- ' + this.weather.main.temp_min

Comment: @Yarom Please open a separate post for new questions.